# File handling comparing string with text file

Tags: java

```
   public static void userClass() throws IOException
   String data="";
    String classroom="";
    System.out.println("Please enter the class");
    classroom = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String subject=classroom.toUpperCase();
    boolean match=false;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
    data = input.readLine();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    data = input.readLine();
    int subjectIndex = 10;
    String items[]=new String [11]; // rows
    while(data!=null)
    {
        data=input.readLine();
        if (data==null)
            break; 
        items=data.split(",");
        for (int x=0; x<items.length; x++)
        {
            if (items.length>10)
            {
                if (items[10].contains(classroom))
                {
                    match=true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (match==true)
    {
        System.out.println("There are " + items[0] + "," + items[1]+  "(" +items[2]+ ")" + " student's enrolling in" +classroom);
    }
    else if (match==false)
    {
        System.out.println("The subject " +subject+ " is not taught at our school");
    }
```

all the students who are enrolled in a course specified by the user

This is the question i tried doing both of them however i kept on getting an error saying `ArraylangIndexBoundException :10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String classroom = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        String data = input.readLine();
        int subjectIndex = 10;
        String[] items = new String[0];
        boolean match=false;
        while (data != null) {
            items = data.split(",");

            if (items.length > 10) {
                if (items[subjectIndex].toLowerCase().contains(classroom)) {
                    System.out.println("There students in enrolling in "  +classroom+ " are " +items[0]+ " " + items[1] + " (" + items[2] +")");
                    match = true;
                }
            }
            data = input.readLine();
        }

        if(!match)
        {
            System.out.println("The subject " +classroom+ " is not taught at our school");
        }

    }
}
```

Input

```
AWQ2O0ECHC2D0ECHV2O0BENG2D0DFSF2D0AGLC2O0BMPM2D0APPL2OMBSNC2D0C
```

Output

```
There students in enrolling in awq2o0echc2d0echv2o0beng2d0dfsf2d0aglc2o0bmpm2d0appl2ombsnc2d0c are Amath Brandon (522442)
 There are 1 students in awq2o0echc2d0echv2o0beng2d0dfsf2d0aglc2o0bmpm2d0appl2ombsnc2d0c
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared items as a 10 element array of strings in userClass() and then you tried to access its eleventh element with the line

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(items[10].split("(?<=\\G.......)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String items[]=new String [10];
boolean match = false; 
int count=0;
```

this line will always fail, as in Java arrays start ith 0 so items[9] is the max.

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(items[10].split("(?<=\\G.......)"));
```

furthermore all your array elements are empty.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your file you have 11 elements so your assignment should be:

   ```
   String items[]=new String [11];
   ```

   Although it's really not necessary, as you can see in the following code:
2. You do not need an array to the last column. You just use the .contains method to determine if the string entered by the user is in the last column.

   ```
   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
   int count=0;    
   while ((data = input.readLine()) != null) {
       String[] items = data.split(",");
       if (items[10].toLowerCase().contains(subject)) {
           System.out.println("There students in enrolling in "  +classroom+ " are " +items[0]+ " " + items[1] + " (" + items[2] + ")");
           count++;            
       }
   }
   if (count==0)
   {
       System.out.println("There subject " + classroom+ " is not taught at our school");
   }
   ```

EDIT:
3. If you want to use the Boolean variable then the code would look like.

```
boolean match=false;
while(data!=null)
{
    data=input.readLine();
    if (data==null)
        break;
    items=data.split(",");
    if (items[10].toLowerCase().contains(subject)) {
        System.out.println("There students in enrolling in "  +classroom+ " are " +items[0]+ " " + items[1] + " (" + items[2] + ")");
        match=true;           
    }
}
if (!match)
{
    System.out.println("There subject " + classroom+ " is not taught at our school");
}
```

Comment: You need to read the entire file to determine who are enrolled in a class.

Comment: The count ++ is just to know if there are students enrolled in a class, if it is zero after reading the file then the message is printed: "There subject __ is not taught at our school"

Comment: If you put on: `(data = input.readLine()) != null` within `While` you'll save 3 lines of code.

Comment: Finally check out my latest edition in 3. And finally, it applies the lessons learned to your other method.

Comment: Check that the file information is as you have indicated. I copied the information and created a file called data.txt and have had no problems even using your code. I do not know because you if you have them.