# Comparing two string in file java

Tags: java

```
String data="";
    System.out.println();  
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
    String items[]=new String [9];
    boolean match = false; 
    int count =0;
    while(data!=null)
    {
        data=input.readLine();
        if (data==null)
            break;
        items=data.split(",");
        if(items[6].equalsIgnoreCase(items[2] ))
        {
            match=true;
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (match==true)
    {
        System.out.println(" There are " +count+ " females are there in Year 3");
    }
    else if (match==false)
    {
        System.out.println("There are not females in Year 3");
    }
}
```

How many females are there in Year 3? This is what i have to do i am new to file-handling so i seriously don't know how i am gonna compare "f" with year 3". Belows is some fake data that my teacher made

```
Amath,Brandon,522442,M,2H1,2D2,S2,970721,2893660440, ,AWQ2O0ECHC2D0ECHV2O0BENG2D0DFSF2D0AGLC2O0BMPM2D0APPL2OMBSNC2D0C
Amber,Joelle,568328,F,4X1,4Q2,S4,950606,9055342231, ,AVI4M0AMCV4U0BMDM4U0BMHF4U0CSBI4U0CSCH4U0A
Amin,Emily,235357,F,BC, ,S1,980416,6478662666, ,CHC2D0EENG2D0FICS2O0BMPM2D0BSNC2D0CTDJ2O0ATEJ2O0ATGJ2O0A
Amin,Oliver,547733,M,4X1,4F2,S4,950130,6471307561, ,BBB4M0ABOH4M0ACLN4U0BCPW4U0BENG4U0FHHS4M0AMDM4U0A
Ananthan,Kamala,437254,F,2D1,3M2,S3,960817,2892548340, ,CLU3E0AENG2P0BENG3C0DGPP3O0AMBF3C0DMFM2P0APAF3OMAPPL3OMB
Anders,Trinidad,674842,F,4M1,4H2,S4,950622,6477645846, ,ENG4U0CMCV4U0BMHF4U0ASBI4U0BSCH4U0CSPH3U0ASPH4U0B
Anderson,Estell,148811,F,1H1,1A2,S1,980317,2895001864, ,ADA1O0BBTT1O0ACGC1D0GENG1D0BFSF1D0DMPM1D0CPAI1OFASNC1D0D
Anderson,Hui,215777,M,4I1,4J2,S4,950715,6470662050, ,BAT4M0ABBB4M0BENG4C0CHZT4U0AMAP4C0BTPJ4C0A
Andresen,Kali,557484,M,4X1,4B2,S4,950826,9053465826, ,GLN4OCDGLC2OCDGLN4O0DHRT3M0AMAP4C0CSBI3C0B
Andropopogiopanatakis,Jann,386122,M,4Q1,2H2,S4,950512,6475802413, ,AVI3M0AAVI4M0ABMI3C0BENG4E0AGLE4O0BMEL4E0AOLC4OIFPPL4OMC
Angus,Rusty,486415,M,4L1,4X4,S4,950321,9051102066, ,BBB4M0ACGR4M0BCHI4U0AENG4C0HHFA4M0AMAP4C0C
Antunes,Patty,286127,F,3F1,4G2,S3,960920,9054824084, ,AVI2O7ABDI3CICENG4U0GHNB4O0AHNC3O0BHPC3OICHSP3M0BMBF3C0D
Aponte,Lacresha,221322,F,1A1,1H2,S1,980109,6476014868, ,AVI1O0ABTT1O0CCGC1D0CENG1D0DFSF1D0DMPM1D0GPAI1OFASNC1D0A
Aramburu,My,585147,F,4D1,4X4,S4,950707,9053410243, ,ENG3U0CHFA4M0BHHG4M0A
Arayaz,Merlin,148728,F,4C1,4F2,S4,950422,6478578314, ,CGR4M0ACHI4U0ACHY4U0BCPW4U0BENG4U0AEWC4U0AMAP4C0EMBF3C0B
Archer,Berna,571327,F,4D1,4L2,S4,950508,9055572668, ,GLN4OCEENG4U0DGLC2OCEGLN4O0EHFA4M0BHHG4M0A
Ashwell,Julee,844262,F,4X1,2E2,S2,970319,9052868453, ,AWQ2O0CCHC2D0DHFN2O0FMPM2D0D
Attrell,ShirlEy,153363,F,3A1,3F2,S4,950106,2891743101, ,AWQ2O0DBOG4E0ABTA3O0AENG4C0FHIR3C0AMEL3EIESBI3C0C
Ayers,Arlena,166658,M,3A1 ,3F2 ,S3,960428,6477376427, ,CHC2D0EENG2D0FICS2O0BMPM2D0BSNC2D0CTDJ2O0ATEJ2O0ATGJ2O0A
```

Comment: I don't know how to do counting and how i would do the question

Comment: Are you sure `if(items[6].equalsIgnoreCase(items[2] ))` is really what you want to do?  And what's the definition for "year 3"?

Comment: S3? and idk i really want that

Comment: if(items[3].equalsIgnoreCase("F") && if(items[6].equalsIgnoreCase("S3))?

Comment: Sound a whole lot closer :)  I'll write an answer now

Comment: ok thanks but how would i count it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        String data = input.readLine();
        int sexIndex = 3;
        int yearIndex = 6;
        String femaleSex = "F";
        String year = "S3";
        int count = 0;
        while (data != null) {
            String[] chunks = data.split(",");

            if (chunks.length >= 6) { // to avoid IndexOutOfBoundException for invalid input
                if (chunks[sexIndex].equalsIgnoreCase(femaleSex) && chunks[yearIndex].equalsIgnoreCase(year)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            data = input.readLine();
        }

        if (count > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(" There are " +count+ " females are there in Year 3");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("There are not females in Year 3");
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
There are 2 females are there in Year 3
```

Comment: sol4me but for me i get 197?

Comment: @Pokemonmaster my data.txt contains all the lines which you pasted in the question

Comment: is because i have more people?

Comment: oh k lol thanks and also would it still count if f is lower case in the data?

Comment: Yes because we are comparing using "equalsIgnoreCase"

Comment: if (chunks.length >= 4), what do u mean by this?

Comment: @Pokemonmaster i updated my answer , basically we are doing it to make sure that if someone by mistake had entered line like "Antunes,Patty,286127" , then code will not throw an exception

Comment: sol4me can u please go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432754/file-handling-comparing-string-with-text-file

Comment: any ideas? for the link i gave u

Comment: @Pokemonmaster I pasted the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432754/file-handling-comparing-string-with-text-file

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the correct condition for the if statement should be

```
if(items[3].equalsIgnoreCase("F") && items[6].equalsIgnoreCase("S3") ) {
```

ie, you want to do something when the conditions

1. the fourth field (arrays are zero-based) matches "f"
2. the seventh field matches "S3"

are both true.

Next

```
    {
        match=true;
        count++;
        break;
    }
```

Here, the break instructs the code to break out of the surrounding loop, ie the `while` loop.  Remove that break and the porgram will actually read all lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear do you mean to count the female students in year 3?
If so the idea (to not give you exact code since its an assignment) is:
Read each line, consider using the more cleaner version:

```
while((data=input.readline())!=null){}
```

Split line and store tokens in array
Check if gender token is female AND if year is equal to 3
Increment your count if so
Do this for all lines 
Print result and exit